# What is the purpose of this two pin component?

Tags: components, identification

What is the purpose of this two pin component (circled)?

It looks to me like a jumper, but it seems strange that it would be so complex for just a jumper (that apparently does nothing). Sits between an AC input and a bridge rectifier.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you remove that part, could be interesting to see a photo of that configuration. I would guess it is for inserting a certain kind of current probe when testing, J11 designation is even weirder.

Comment: The unpopulated (or removed) part besides it looks like it would be in a similar configuration. Maybe if you remove it there is a trace underneath and then it is not a jumper, just a terminal.

Comment: Looks like a horizontal spade connector receptacle.

Comment: Could it be some kind of slide-on mounting bracket?

Comment: Post an image with a wider view of the PCB.

Comment: 0
down vote

It looks like a resettable thermal fuse which remakes the circuit when the overload is removed.

Comment: Leon Heller, If it was a fuse it shouldn't be labeled J14.

Comment: Is that the only component on the board which looks like that? Is there a similar looking one located elsewhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a solderless spade connector, soldered to the PCB.

Like this:
http://www.keyelco.com/product-pdf.cfm?p=681

[image]

(www.digikey.com Keystone: 3547)

Comment: Any suggestions on why it was used there? I thought those things were for removable ground connections, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Mast, maybe it's used as an auxiliary power input for standalone testing of the board?

Comment: @BrockAdams Perhaps, but I'd have expected another one of those in the other AC track if that was the case.

Comment: @Mast, it might be offscreen.  Wouldn't want 2 AC lugs in such close proximity.

Comment: @BrockAdams Hah, good point.

Comment: Solderless connector that's soldered ;)

Comment: I also find it interesting that the signal flows _through_ this component, even though it serves only as a 'jack'.  This makes this component a required part for the board to function (it, or something like it, which shorts the two pads must be installed), even though it serves no function for circuit operation.